# which layout should be used for this example

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, user-interface

Which `Android` `layout` would be best suited for this example. Inside each box would be a picture. I am mainly wondering what would be the best parent layout for the entire screen.

I was probably going to use `TableLayout` for each of the rows of boxes. Then have each column in the `TableLayout` be a `FrameLayout`. Then have each `FrameLayout` contain the picture.

But i am not sure what parent `Layout` i should use to contain the entire screen.

I would like this to be able to fit in `Landscape` on the majority of the phones on the market. Maybe it resizes everything to fit those screens in landscape.

I would also like there to be spacing between those `TableLayouts`.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[image]

Comment: Drawing the screen border would help understand the problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were building that, and the number of images/boxes in each set was static, I would probably use `RelativeLayout` as the parent and `LinearLayout` for each of the "rows." Then just use `ImageView` directly as children of the `LinearLayout`. `RelativeLayout` allows you to position things relative to each other or the parent.

Comment: I was thinking that `RelativeLayout` would be what i would need. But i just needed some reassurance. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Either `RelativeLayout` or `GridView` whichever fulfills the exact requirement.